# Issues with basic rules in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to translate my natural code in `prolog`.

Here is my natural code :

```
if E < W then
   if C < Max then
      print('increment C')
   else
      print('C unchanging')
if E > W then
   if C > Min then
      print('decrement C')
   else
      print('error')
```

Here is my code in SWI-Prolog :

```
tddv_worst(_).
tddv_best(_).
tddv_courant(_).
tddv_estime(_).
etendue_gisement_courant(_).
etendue_gisement_min(_).
etendue_gisement_max(_).

compromis_1(tddv_estime(E),tddv_worst(W),etendue_gisement_courant(C),etendue_gisement_min(Min),etendue_gisement_max(Max)) :-
(E < W , C < Max) -> writeln('Increment C') ; writeln('C unchanging') ;
(E > W , C > Min) -> writeln('Decrement C') ; writeln('Error').
```

When I write this in the interpreter :

> compromis_1(tddv_estime(19),tddv_worst(16),etendue_gisement_courant(2),etendu e_gisement_max(8),etendue_gisement_min(1)).

It displays `C unchanging`.

It's not supposed to display this.

Can someone explain me why ?

Comment: Yes, i know but i don't understand why the comma is not correct in the comparison statement

Comment: You only have 1 rule. A rule is marked with `:-`. What you have are a bunch of `if` statements within a single rule. You also have a bunch of random facts defined for no apparent reason. Your `if` always succeeds either with a `then` or `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation isn't really equivalent to the C version you are showing.

Here's your current code:

```
(E < W , C < Max) -> writeln('Increment C') ;
writeln('C unchanging') ;
(E > W , C > Min) -> writeln('Decrement C') ;
writeln('Error').
```

Prolog sees this as a series of four clauses related by a logical disjunction (OR -- `;`). If the first `->` expression fails, it then calls the next disjunctive expression, `writeln('C unchanging')`. The above code is roughly equivalent to:

```
if E < W and C < Max then
   print('increment C')
else
   print('C unchanging')

if E > W and C > Min then
   print('decrement C')
else
   print('error')
```

A Prolog equivalent of your original pseudo-code would be:

```
(   E < W
->  (   C < Max
    ->  writeln('increment C')
    ;   writeln('C unchanging')
    )
) ;
(   E > W
->  (   C > Min
    ->  writeln('decrement C')
    ;   writeln('Error')
    )
)
```

In Prolog, this behavior happens to work like the pseudo-code since `->` eliminates the choice point if it succeeds and Prolog will not backtrack.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I tried with your equivalent and now it works !